# Finding all matrices that satisfy a 'wrong property'

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, inverse

I was reminded of a very usual highschool algebra question of a 'wrong property' where students usually just 'distribute squares' like: $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2$. Clearly this is wrong and that if we solve this equation anyway, then we arrive at $2xy = 0.$ This means that the solution set for which this 'wrong property' holds is when you have any real number $x$ and $y=0$, or both are zero.

Coming to linear algebra, we have a quite similar common misconception that $(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{B}^{-1}$. My question is, can we find all $2\times 2$ matrices that satisfy this equation?

I tried solving this, but it is proving a bit difficult, so I made some assumptions like let $\mathbf{A}$ be the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}_2$, can we find all $\mathbf{B}$ that satisfies this 'wrong property'?

Comment: It seems to me that in algebra, $\frac{1}{r} = s \iff sr=1.$  I don't know matrix theory from a giraffe, so, with *a lot of salt*, what about $(A + B) \times \left(A^{-1} + B^{-1}\right) = I$?

Comment: If you multiply on the right by $(\mathbf A + \mathbf B)\mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf B$, you get a quadratic in the matrix $\mathbf M = \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf B$. Then by completing the square we see that it's a necessary condition that $\tfrac 2{\sqrt 3}(\mathbf M + \tfrac 12 \mathbf I_2)$ (or something similar) squares to $-\mathbf I_2$. But these square roots are [fairly well understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix#Identity_matrix). I'm not sure if there's a way to get a necessary and sufficient condition from here, but probably it can generate some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets work with $n\times n$ matrices, and later focus on $n=2.$ It is easy to prove that $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is really the inverse of $A(A + B) ^{−1}B,$ not $A+B.$ Also $$(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=I \iff AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}+I=0.$$

**Theorem**
There are two square matrices satisfying this condition if and only if their dimension $n$ is even. Moreover there is a one to one correspondence between complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $AB^{-1}.$
Proof:
Let $C=AB^{-1}$ be a non-identity matrix, then the last condition is equivalent to saying that $$C+C^{-1}+I=0 \iff C^3=I.$$ Now, $J=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(I+2C)$ has the property that $J^2=-I,$  i.e., $J$ is a complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then $\det(J)^2=(-1)^n$ implies that $n$ must be even.

Conversely, if $n=2m$ is even, then we can define a complex structure $J: \mathbb{R}^{2m}\to \mathbb{R}^{2m}$  by picking a basis $\{e_1, e_2,\cdots, e_m, e_{m+1},\cdots, e_{2m}\}$ and mapping  $J(e_r)=e_{m+r}$ and $J(e_{m+r})=-e_r$ for all $r=1, 2, \cdots, m.$ So, $J^2=-I$ and the previous equation $C=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{3}J-I)$ defines a matrix $C$ with the desire property.

In fact, this proof can use as an algorithm to explicitly compute such matrices $C,$ and hence $A=CB$ for any invertible matrix $B,$ in any even dimension $n.$

**Added:** We can parametrize all complex structures on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $$J_{\theta, \lambda}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sinh \theta & -\lambda\cosh \theta \\
\dfrac{1}{\lambda} \cosh \theta & -\sinh \theta
\end{pmatrix},\qquad \lambda\neq0.$$ Hence there is a complete description of all $2\times 2$ matrices with this wrong property.

Comment: Cool stuff! Is it obvious that this $C$ will be invertible?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: Good point. It is invertible because of its characteristic polynomial $C^2+C+I=0.$ Also, the simplest case is $$ J=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ and is not hard to compute $C$ and check its invertibility.

Comment: Of course, good point! I really like your answer!

Comment: may I know where $J = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(I+2C)$ came from?

Comment: Nice to see the symplectic matrix make an all-of-a-sudden appearance in this problem!

Comment: @cgo: It is the trick that produces a complex structure $J$ from  a matrix with the property $C^2+C+I=0.$ If you like an analogy, there are no real numbers with that satisfies $\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac1{a+b}.$ But in $\mathbb{C}$ there are infinitely many solutions with $$c=\frac12(\sqrt{3}i-1)$$ (i.e., $c^2+c+1=0$) where $c=\frac{a}{b}.$

Comment: Can you kindly name that theorem or property? I was thinking something like a complex generalisation of Cayley Hamilton, no?

Comment: @cgo: I am unaware of a specific name for it. But you might find something by googling, I suppose.